# Spanish-language (translated?) comic containing multiple short stories (Atlantis, time-travel, space colonisation...)

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization, atlantis

This comic would probably be from the 70s and belonged to my father, but unfortunately got lost when moving house. It was in Spanish, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was translated from a different language -or was inspired by some other original sources.

There were multiple stories. I remember 3, can't say if there were more:

- A colony spaceship that crash-lands on a sort of New Eden planet,
  with only a man and a woman surviving, leading to a sort of new Adam
  & Eve scenario.
- An abandoned space outpost in some planet (maybe Mars?) that seems fine except for the lack of its crew. The space travelers that arrive
  to investigate it shortly discover that when a given sun / planet
  alignment takes places, a portal opens and some sort of space
  barbarians cross it, killing everything they found (I think they
  might be riding some sort of horses, like the Knights of the
  Apocalypse?).
- An explorer in a submarine ship that goes underwater to find two humanoid figures fighting each other. The explorer manages to
  interrupt their fight but one of them is too badly injured and dies.
  The other recovers to explain they were the last survivors from two
  opposing factions in Atlantis. When the explorer attempts to go back
  to the surface to present his finding, they arrive to see everything
  destroyed by some sort of war (to which the survivor makes some
  remark about them sharing the same fate). The "Atlantean" goes back
  to the sea while the human falls to his knees in despair (either this
  was a homage to the Planet of the Apes, or I mixed two similar
  representations of the same idea)

The comic style was very clean and realistic.

**EDIT**

1. I couldn't find anything related to the first story in TV Tropes,
   but I'll use the new Eden / Adam & Eve keywords when searching more.
2. In the second story, The travelers are killed, and the outpost is left abandoned, implying that the next visitors are likely to meet the same destiny.
3. In the third story, the two Atlantean are naked, have some sort of fin attached to their ankles, so they swim better, and have long hair and beards. They might be of green colour, but I'm not entirely sure.

Although I don't remember any explicit sex, the realism of the picture made it adult-oriented rather than teenager / young adult. I'm pretty sure it was in colour.

**EDIT2**

I'm no longer sure it was in colour, and I can't say if the publisher / edition was Spanish or Latin American. However, I found Spanish comic book artist [Esteban Maroto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esteban_Maroto). [His style](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=esteban%20maroto&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images) is quite similar to what I think I remember, meaning this would probably have been written originally in Spanish.

Comment: Those are some really good details! Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for some tips to see if you can elicit a few more. And also do please visit the [tour] (you'll get a badge for it!) to learn how to judge and accept answers.

Comment: The first one is a fairly standard ["Adam and Eve" plot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdamAndEvePlot) (warning, TV Tropes link), so you might glance through the Comics section and see if any titles look familiar.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the publisher origin or can pinpoint somehow if Spanish was of European or Latin America origin?

Comment: Alfonso Font is another Spanish artist with a style similar to Maroto's. He has done a lot of science fiction comics in both short and long formats. I don't recall the stories in question, though - but I have only read what little has been translated into Danish. https://www.lambiek.net/artists/f/font_alfonso.htm

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen, thanks for your comment. I have checked Alfonso Font (and realised I had read his Tales of an Imperfect Future), and I don't think it was him in the story. In parallel I have been searching for Esteban Maroto's work, and I'm trying to buy a collection that might have the first story I listed there (called _Paraíso_ (_Paradise_) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stories you remember were published by the [Spanish comic magazine "Trinca"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinca_(comic)) in biweekly installments between 1970 and 1973. Their artist was [Alfonso Azpiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfonso_Azpiri) and the scriptwriter of most of them was [Carlos Saiz Cidoncha](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Saiz_Cidoncha).

This is the cover of the number 61 (year 1973) that includes the story "Superviviente," which is the one about the Atlantis survivor.

[image]

In addition, since the closure of the magazine in 1973 and until 1978, the publishing house Doncel published some compilations of many stories published in its magazine. The issue that includes the stories of Azpiri and Cidoncha (and some scripted by [Carlos Buiza](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Buiza)) was published in 1975 and entitled: ["Alpha Cosmos"](https://www.tebeosfera.com/numeros/trinca_1971_doncel_27.html).

[image]

Azpiri became in the 1980's an inspirational artist for a generation of computer game fans, especially the ZX Spectrum home computer, very popular in Britain and Spain.

[image]

Cidoncha was an usual and highly endearing figure of the Spanish science fiction fan conventions (Hispacón).

Comment: This is amazing. The one we had at home was Alpha Cosmos, exactly that one! This is a blast from the past, thank you so much!

Comment: @HoneyConfusion I have on a hard drive scans of almost every Trinca magazine. Since the publisher went out of business decades ago, I don't think I'm doing anything wrong if I send you a copy. ;)

Comment: Absolutely :-) I don't know how to move this conversation to chat - or how to chat in StackExchange, I'm open to ideas

Comment: The one I will try to get is "Alpha Cosmos". I found they have it in lamansion-crg.net, but it's a link peer to peer download that I can't follow right now (hopefully at home). In [ALPHA COSMOS](https://www.tebeosfera.com/numeros/trinca_1971_doncel_27.html) they list the stories the collection had, so worst case, I'll try to get the Trinca magazine issues that had them in the first place :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103935/discussion-between-honeyconfusion-and-ginasius).